# Number of ways to distribute $k$ identical objects into $n$ boxes, where each box contains at most one object

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, balls-in-bins

> Number of ways to distribute $k$ identical objects into $n$ boxes, where each box contains at most one object

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything here in the forum. The question may already have been answered. If so, I apologize in advance and would be grateful if someone could post the link here. The problem is the following:

Given $k$ identical objects and $n$ boxes where $k \leq n$. How many ways are there to divide these $k$ objects into $n$ boxes such that each box contains at most one object? This can also be formulated as follows: How many solutions does the following problem have?

$$
x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n = k \\
x_i \in \{0,1\} \quad \forall~i = 1, \ldots, n,
$$
where $x_i$ denotes the $i$-th box.

Comment: Why isn't this just $\binom nk$?

Comment: Is it that simple? Did I think too complicated? :D

Comment: I mean, you just need to specify which boxes are non-empty.  Unless you also meant the boxes to be undistinguishable, in which case the answer is just $1$.

Comment: Still interesting. Now I know that one can represent the binomial coefficient as the number of solutions to the above problem :D

Comment: The answer would be $k!$ times bigger if both the balls and the boxes were distinguishable

Comment: The reason that it is $\displaystyle~\binom{n}{k}~$ is that you are (in effect) choosing $k$ of the $n$ (distinguishable) boxes, without replacement.  As other comments have indicated, since the objects are identical, the **order** that the $k$ boxes are chosen is **not relevant**.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for the comment!